# Error while running the app using emulator Gradle sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the following error when trying to run my very first app on emulator in android studio 
Please help:
Gradle sync failed: 
Unable to start the daemon process.
           This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
           For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
           Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.8/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
           Please read the following process output to find out more:
           -----------------------
           Error occurred during initialization of VM
           Could not reserve enough space for object heap
           Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
           Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Answer (score 1):

> Probably, the /tmp location is full..

Use df command

```
$df
```

You should see an output with a line like this:

```
tmpfs 102400 102312 88 100% /tmp
```

So to change the size of the tmp file:

```
sudo mount -o remount,size=2G /tmp
```

Done!
Now, It should work..